# is there any opensource or free license Control project

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls, c++-cli

is there any opensource or free license Control project that has fantasy looking and feel just like DevExpress?
could you give some links.. if it isn't opensource, free licensed DLL is ok.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/), by Microsoft.

Comment: Can I use this in my Winform project? just now i intalled one ,but seems it can't be used in my winfrom project :(

Comment: No, it's for WPF apps. Didn't realize you weren't looking for WPF stuff by the question tags.